# Finding error range for peak point using polynomial fitting

Tags: python

I have data for a spectral line which makes a noisy U shaped curve .
I want to fit a curve and find the x,y values for the minimum point .
I then fitted a polynomial to it using polyfit .
I then found to minimum point on the fitted curve .
NB: The original curve is not symmetric (The left side is slightly steeper than the right .) 
Therefore the min(original) is slightly left of min(fitted_curve) 
How do I find the X and Y errors for this point ?
Here are the bones of my code :

```
import pylab , numpy

x = [... linear list of floats ...]
y = [... list of floats ...]    # Produces a noisy U shaped curve .

fit = numpy.polyfit(x,y,3) 
fit2 = numpy.polyval(fit,x)     # Fit a third order polynomial .  

miny = # min y value on fitted curve .
minx = # corresponding x value , not the actually min(x) .

pylab.plot(x,y,'k-')
pylab.plot(x,fitt,'r-')
pylab.plot(minx,miny,'ro')
pylab.show()
```

Now that I have the original [x,y]  , the fitted curve  [x,fitt2]  and the minimum point on the fitted curve [minx,miny] , how do I find the error range for this single point ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

For numpy 1.7 the `polyfit` has the option `cov=True`. You get as additional output the covariance matrix. From this, using Gaussian error propagation, you can get the error of the minimum. But what kind of spectrum is it? Very often there are model shapes to fit, such that there is no need for the polynomial fit.

You might also want to look at `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`

PS: What makes you think that the true value is left of your fitted value. This would be true if your fit function was symmetric, being applied to the asymmetric peak. The third order polynomial, however, should be able to address asymmetry.